# EntityFramework query between three tables with many to many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I need a query which selects a `Descrizione` from table `Funzionalita` by given `Dipendente` object. I pass the `Dipendente` into lower shown method (it's part of a Web API).

All relations are `many-to-many` and here is a screenshot of my database model:

[image]

Above mentioned method:

```
public bool PostLogin(Dipendente dipendente)
{
    try
    {
        UfficioPostiEntities1 db = new UfficioPostiEntities1();
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        var ruolo = db.Dipendente.Include("Ruolo").ToList(); //Buona
        var funzionalita = db.Ruolo.Include("Funzionalita").ToList();

        Dipendente user = db.Dipendente.FirstOrDefault(
            x => x.Username == dipendente.Username 
            && x.Password == dipendente.Password);

        if (user != null)
        {
            var r = ruolo[0];
            
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }                
    }
}
```

I wrote a method but doesn't work.

Comment: What is you exact question? Do you get an exception?

Comment: I can not make the exact query...i need query between tre tables whit relationship many to many, se the linked image

Comment: Have you tried to use navigation properties? Such as `db.Funzionalita.Where(w => w.Ruolo.Dipendente.IdDependente == dipendente.IdDependente).Select(s => s.Descrizione).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: yes because return me an error, ICollection<Ruolo> 
does not contain a definition of 'Dipendente' and no extension method 'Dipendente' has been found that accepts a first argument of type ICollection <ruolo>

Comment: i have wrote a query on sql server...i need the same in linq or lambda expression or any type, `SELECT     dbo.Funzionalita.IdFunzionalita, dbo.Dipendente.Username, dbo.Dipendente.Password, dbo.Funzionalita.Descrizione
FROM         dbo.Ruolo INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Dipendente INNER JOIN
                      dbo.DipendenteRuolo ON dbo.Dipendente.IdDipendente = dbo.DipendenteRuolo.Dipendente_Id ON dbo.Ruolo.IdRuolo = dbo.DipendenteRuolo.Ruolo_Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.RuoloFunzionalita INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Funzionalita ON `

Comment: `dbo.RuoloFunzionalita.Funzionalita_Id = dbo.Funzionalita.IdFunzionalita ON dbo.Ruolo.IdRuolo = dbo.RuoloFunzionalita.Ruolo_Id
WHERE     (dbo.Dipendente.Username = 'gg') AND (dbo.Dipendente.Password = 'tt')`

Comment: Try this: `db.Funzionalita.Where(w => w.Ruolo.Where(r => r.Dipendente.Where(d => d.IdDependente == dipendente.IdDependente))).Select(s => s.Descrizione).FirstOrDefault()`